# Changing URL in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp.net website. The Admin panel is located here:

> mysite.com/manager

I want to change this to:

> mysite.com/admin

There is no file named `manager` in the website files and I'm unsure how to make this change or locate the manager source file.

Comment: Google "URL Aliasing in ASP.NET". There are numerous ways to do this, some of them open source.

Comment: I guess you did not build the website your self but using a off the shelf software. What software are you using?

Comment: Yes. I haven't made the website. It was made by some developer. But now i have to change this one myself. I'm using Visual studio 2012.

Comment: Aside from being too broad, what's this question got to do with sql-server???

Comment: Is there a folder named "manager"? Could be structured into multiple 'Areas'.

Comment: @Tanner I'm sorry if it doesn't suit with sql-server. I thought, because there is no file or folder named "manager" so it may be fetched from the database.

Comment: @adiga There is no folder or file named "manager" in the website files.

Comment: If he wants to store his URL mappings in SQL Server, it's relevant. I've actually done exactly what the OP is trying to accomplish - there was an open source ASP.NET 2.0 URL rewriter I used back in 2007. It was XML based but I modified it to use a SQL Server database. I don't have the code anymore since I left the company, but I've done this and I know it's possible. This system will most likely work in a 4.0 webforms site. (Based on the other post, MVC includes this functionality)

Comment: @Tim it could, but without showing any details of code/schema it has no relation to sql-server at this point. So that tag is not relevant unless some schema or code points to it being relevant.

Comment: This code is from URLHelper.cs
http://pastebin.com/81XtEejb
I think from this code the URL is being fetched from the **SiteHelper.cs**
But there is nothing like **manager** in there

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it's unlikely to be related to a database in anyway.

Sounds like your project is using **[MVC and Routing](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs)**:

> The ASP.NET Routing module is responsible for mapping incoming browser requests to particular MVC controller actions

If so, your web project will have a folder called "Controllers" and within that there will be a file called "ManagerController.cs".

Within this file, you'll see a method that looks like:

```
public virtual ActionResult Index()
{
    // some code maybe
    return View();
}
```

This is what will be called when that URL is hit.

You may also want to search for a file called `RouteConfig.cs`, which is located in the `App_Start` folder, where any non-standard routes will be configured.

To make the change, you can copy and rename `ManagerController.cs` to `AdminController.cs` and MVC will work it's magic as the default routing will search for that file instead.

Comment: its not MVC. It has these Folder 1) App_code-->Sub-directories are 1.Database 2. Handlers 3. Utility.) 2) App_Data 3) bin 4)Resources-->Having files Frontend.aspx, Backend.aspx 5) Uploads 6)

I have Gone through every file and folder but i coudn't find "manager" in there.